# Which method will be used to getItemCount (no of cards) when using MDCCardCollectionCell?

Tags: ios, swift, mdc-components, materialcardview

I am new to IOS.I used to work as Android developer.
I am using `MDCCardCollectionCell`/`MDCCard` for Cardviews in my project.
When i was working on android, to display number of cards - we used to return number in `getItemCount()` Adapter class.
Similarly, i want to know which method (or) where should we return cards count?

Example : if i give return 4 , 4 cardviews should display on screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `numberOfItemsInSection` method for the count of total items.

check this example [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/blob/7c481c023ef2fa01e8ab0824a58e3ae6bc648303/demos/Pesto/Pesto/PestoCollectionViewController.m#L89)

Comment: please accept this answer if your query is resolved.